# xUnit tests not discovered

Tags: c#, .net-core, xunit, .net-5

It's the first time I'm trying xUnit tests in .NET 5 and it seems broken for what I can see.

Here's a simple class

```
public class UnitTest1
{
    [Fact]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("");
        Assert.IsTrue(true);
    }
}
```

And here are my references

[image]

Also, here's my test project .csproj definition

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>

    <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
  </PropertyGroup>


<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions" Version="2.2.0" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost" Version="5.0.5"/>
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="16.7.1" />
  <PackageReference Include="MSTest.TestAdapter" Version="2.1.1" />
  <PackageReference Include="MSTest.TestFramework" Version="2.1.1" />
  <PackageReference Include="coverlet.collector" Version="1.3.0" />
  <PackageReference Include="xunit.extensibility.core" Version="2.4.1" />
  <PackageReference Include="xunit.runner.visualstudio" Version="2.4.3">
  <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
  <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; 
buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
</PackageReference>
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\BusinessLayer.SecurityGateway.Services\BusinessLayer.SecurityGateway.Services.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

I get an error saying no tests were discovered

```
[xUnit.net 00:00:00.00] xUnit.net VSTest Adapter v2.4.3+1b45f5407b (64-bit .NET 5.0.4)
No test is available in \xUnitTests.SecurityGateway\bin\Debug\net5.0\xUnitTests.SecurityGateway.dll. Make sure that test discoverer & executors are registered and platform & framework version settings are appropriate and try again.
```

I'm not sure what I'm supposed to check as I don't know what is "discoverer & executors" and what those settings are.

I have update Visual Studio 2019 Preview to the latest version, as of 10 mins ago.

Last time I used this was in .net core 3.1 and it worked out of the box right away.

Comment: Can you post your csproj file?

Comment: I don't see an explicit package reference to `xunit`. Not sure if that's necessary, but try adding a nuget package reference to xunit 2.4.1.

Comment: @gunr2171 Seems to have fixed it. I was using `Assert` from the wrong package (Microsoft's instead of xUnit) as well. Thanks.

Comment: I just wanted to add, if you are trying to test a project that does not run on its own, like a library, do a quick sanity check and make sure that the project is building without errors. Tests get discovered when the project builds, and because the project was "working" it never occurred to me to do the easiest thing first and verify my library was building without issue.